# Why does Inkscape not preserve Unicode text when importing PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, unicode, inkscape, svg

I have a PDF made from Word, and importing it into Inkscape. The text (which are non-ASCII) doesn't correct. Here is the original:

[image]

And here is the imported:

[image]

Moreover, if I edit the text, it behaves strange:

[image]

Do you know why is that?